# Wavelength and propagation constant relation

Tags: electromagnetism, wavelength, waveguide

**Theory**

Propagation constant is equal to: $\gamma = j k_z = \alpha + j \beta$

Wavelength: $\lambda = \frac{2 \pi}{Im\{ \gamma \}}$

Wave impedance:

1. $Z_{TEM} = \frac{\gamma }{ j \omega \epsilon } = \frac{j \omega \mu}{\gamma}$
2. $Z_{TE} = \frac{j \omega \mu}{\gamma}$
3. $Z_{TM} = \frac{\gamma }{ j \omega \epsilon }$

**Question**:

Why do we ignore propagation constant ($\alpha$) in the definition of wavelength?

**Food for thought**

propagation constant is not ignored in wave impedance formulas, so what is going on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.